# Ubuntu 14.04 bluetooth mouse lags time by time

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-62-generic (buildd@lgw01-59) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #102-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:29:36 UTC 2015
```

and

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

And I have also my bluetooth mouse sometimes starts lagging. This exacerbation can take about one day, after that it just stops lagging and working perfectly. It looks like chronic illness.

It's on HP-Envy 6-1154er.

I have found similar issues on the web, but not answered. It's really annoying thing.

Any ideas?

**Updated**

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb
01:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1896]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4062]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:c336 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20329 SATA Bridge
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0"
```

and reboot.

Bluetooth coexistence technology in `iwlwifi` is not good and makes things worse.

Comment: Thank you man! You killed three birds. Mouse now works! Wi-Fi also started working as it should! And the third, you saved my nerves!

Comment: Where did you see that this was activated? Also, why is "Bluetooth coexistence technology" bad? How this will affect my ability to use Bluetooth and Wi-Fi at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and location is slightly different:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf.backup

$ sudo echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

I also tried run the following commands post reboot:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r btusb

$ sudo modprobe btusb
```

Thanks for the original info it seem to work

Comment: You can add as many configuration files in the directory /etc/modeprobe.de/. and name them like you want. So an additional one makes no problems but will keep things clean. This also will safe you from making backup files like you did ;-)

Unfortunately the solution did not help me ... :-(

Comment: is this the same for 18.04?