# Bluetooth Mouse Lag

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have a BlueTooth mouse (Dell WM524). Works like a charm on my notebook with Ubuntu 15, but I have a little issue...

Recently I've bought a 23' full HD monitor and started using on notebook, no problems with system performance, Ubuntu crashes, or everything else, except for the BlueTooth mouse, that has a lot of lag

Probably is a problem about hardware performance, but all the system is going fine, why the BT needs to lag? Is there a way to increase BT priority on Ubuntu?

Important: It's only BlueTooth mouse that lags, wired mouse doesn't have any problem. When the monitor is disconnected that problem doesn't happen.

So, can I fix this increasing the BlueTooth priority process, or doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the "Sync To VBlank" setting in "OpenGL", which you can deactivate via the CompizConfig Settings Manager as reported in [Mouse lag after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460477/mouse-lag-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04#461889).

---

**Note:** I say, "could be", because you're mentioning the monitor, hence it may be graphics related. I have [the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464427/bluetooth-mouse-lagging#comment-1260087), though without an external monitor, and the bluetooth mouse (Logitech Ultrathin Touch Mouse) just worked fine before upgrading from 14.04 LTS, and lagging afterwards. Unfortunately, for me the OpenGL setting doesn't solve the problem.

I tried the approach in [Ubuntu 14.04 bluetooth mouse lags time by time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663500/ubuntu-14-04-bluetooth-mouse-lags-time-by-time#answer-663889), which remediated the mouse lag slightly, almost unnoticeably. The lag is still there. On my system, the problem seems to be that the [driver is not loaded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767046/bluetooth-broadcom-bcm20702-does-not-load-firmware-driver-issue-14-04):

```
$ dmesg | grep bluetooth
[    5.159573] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
[  292.300110] input: Ultrathin Touch Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:046D:B00D.0004/input/input18
```