# Razer Orochi bluetooth mouse connects but doesn't work (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: mouse, 16.04, bluetooth

I've just bought Razer Orochi wireless mouse, it works perfectly when connected via wire, but bluetooth connection doesn't work. First time when I've tried to connect it via blueman, it failed, next time it was already connected. In blueman it's unknown, in ubuntu default bluetooth settings it is shown as mouse.

What can I do about it?

Any help/suggestions gladly appreciated.

PS: I don't need any led color modifications, I don't care about it at all. I just want it to work without cable.

Answer (score 1):

It magicaly works now! Maybe some recent updates made it work, or something magical has happend. I had lag issues but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663500/ubuntu-14-04-bluetooth-mouse-lags-time-by-time) has solved my problem.

EDIT:
The problem was I am using bluetooth speakers and it's not possible to use both at same time.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( Strange thing is that mouse suddenly started working and worked for few days but then it stopped as magicaly as it started... Have no idea what I've done back then. Tried to remove device, add device, trust, untrust, pair, unpair, nothing seems to help.

Comment: Heh :D previous comment supposed to be addressed to answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble connecting this too, but eventually I tried:

```
sudo hciconfig down
sudo hciconfig up
```

And now it's working.

Comment: Not working for me :(